# break outside the loop error in python

Tags: python

I'm created simple bank programme where i create four methods for the transaction. below is my code. the problem is it shows an error that "break outside the loop".
kindly help, I'm new to python.

```
bal=0
def deposit():
    global bal
    amount=input('Enter Deposit Amount: ')
    bal=bal+amount

def withdraw():
    global bal
    amount=input('Enter Withdraw Amount: ')
    bal=bal-amount

def checkbal():
    global bal
    print bal

def conti():
    c=raw_input('Do You Wana Continue y/n....')
    if c=='y':
       main()
    else:
       break   

def main():
    print '---Welcome To ABC Bank---'
    print 'Enter 1 For Deposit:'
    print 'Enter 2 For Withdraw:'
    print 'Enter 3 For Balance Check:'
    print 'Enter 4 For Exit:'
    choice= input('Enter Your Choice :')

if(choice==1):
    deposit()
elif(choice==2):
    withdraw()
elif(choice==3):
    checkbal()
else:
    print 'Invalid Entry'

conti()

main()
```

Comment: replace break   with return "" in def conti

Comment: What line is the error on? Is there a break there? Is it within a loop (`while` or `for`)? If not, why did you use break there?

Comment: A few unrelated notes: 1) you don't need parenthesis around `if`/`elif` conditions, 2) you should be learning on Python 3 since 2.7 will be EOL soon (which requires parenthesis for print, so you should be doing `print('hello')`), 3) `bal = bal - amount` and `bal = bal + amount` can be just `bal -= amount` and `bal += amount`, respectively

Comment: Aren't you missing `elif choice == 4: conti()`? Also, that part probably should be in `main`.

Comment: Just check there ..If you enter 4 it won't exit. It will print `Invalid  Entry`. Also If you exit from `conti()` I don't think so you will exit from program. Because again `main()` is there .

Comment: @VikasDamodar While I think the `if choice...` block should be in `main`, the call to `main` is probably meant to be outside of `main`, otherwise the program would not run at all.

Comment: I think @tobias_k comment is make sense, he needs to check `choice==4` and of course the `if` part should be in `main()`

Answer (score 2):

> break outside the loop

it means you use `break` not inside a loop. `break` is only used inside a loop when you want to stop the iteration.

So, in this code:

```
def conti():
    c=raw_input('Do You Wana Continue y/n....')
    if c=='y':
       main()
    else:
       break  # should be exit()
```

If you want to exit from program if user choose not to continue, then `break` should be `exit()`

or `return` if you just want to exit from `conti()` function. (But it means you still go to `main()` function)

Comment: exactly .. still need more corrections in his program .. Just check and mention that also in your answer .I think it will helps him more .

Answer (score 0):

```
def conti():
  c=raw_input('Do You Wana Continue y/n....')
  if c=='y':
    main()
  else:
    break
```

You can use return statement in place of break because break will come outside the loop whereas return will return you to main function else if you want to come out of program you can simply use exit()

Comment: The `exit` is somewhat redundant, as `conti()` seems to be the last statement in `main` anyways (assuming wrong indentation), but `return` is even more redundant, as it would be the last statement in the function. Also, don't just copy code from other answers!